# How to change content position when in full screen mode for xaringan slides

Tags: html, css, r-markdown, remarkjs, xaringan

I am recording a video that will put myself and the xaringan slides side by side. Therefore, I would like to float the container of the slides to the right side so that I will have space to stand at the left.

Here is an example slide:

````
---
title: "Incremental Slides with xaringan / remark.js"
author: "Yihui Xie"
date: "2017/08/31"
output:
  xaringan::moon_reader:
    css: ["test.css", "default", "default-fonts"]
    lib_dir: libs
    nature:
      countIncrementalSlides: false
      ratio: '16:9'
---

```{r setup, include=FALSE}
options(htmltools.dir.version = FALSE)
```

# Three ways to build incremental slides

In remark.js, you may use
````

And here is the CSS code I tried to move the container to right:

```
html.remark-container, body.remark-container {
  width: 93%;
  float: right;
}

.remark-container:-webkit-full-screen {
  width: 93%;
  height: 100%;
  float: right;
}
```

After rending the slides, the position is what I want when it is NOT in full screen. But after enter the presentation or full screen mode, the container is centered and I do not know how to move it to the right side. Any ideas? Thanks!

And here is my session information:

```
R version 3.4.2 Patched (2017-10-01 r73429)
Platform: x86_64-apple-darwin15.6.0 (64-bit)
Running under: macOS High Sierra 10.13.1

Matrix products: default
BLAS: /System/Library/Frameworks/Accelerate.framework/Versions/A/Frameworks/vecLib.framework/Versions/A/libBLAS.dylib
LAPACK: /Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Versions/3.4/Resources/lib/libRlapack.dylib

locale:
[1] en_US.UTF-8/en_US.UTF-8/en_US.UTF-8/C/en_US.UTF-8/en_US.UTF-8

attached base packages:
[1] stats     graphics  grDevices utils     datasets  methods   base     

loaded via a namespace (and not attached):
 [1] compiler_3.4.2  backports_1.1.1 magrittr_1.5    rsconnect_0.8   rprojroot_1.2   htmltools_0.3.6 tools_3.4.2     xaringan_0.4.4 
 [9] yaml_2.1.14     Rcpp_0.12.13.2  stringi_1.1.5   rmarkdown_1.7   knitr_1.17.9    stringr_1.2.0   digest_0.6.12   evaluate_0.10.1
```

Comment: I ended up with using the full mode of the browser (i.e. F11 on Windows) instead of full mode of remark.

Answer (score 1):

You should [inspect the CSS classes](https://bookdown.org/yihui/blogdown/website-basics.html) when your slides is fullscreen. My guess is that the class names might be different.

I don't have time to answer your question directly, but [here is an indirect answer](https://yihui.name/en/2017/12/html5-camera/). The two key pieces are: (1) you can embed a video through your camera using the `navigator.getUserMedia()` API, e.g.,

```
<video autoplay id="webcam" width="200" height="200" style="position:absolute;top:0;right:0;z-index:100;cursor:move;" draggable="true"></video>

<script>
(function() {
  if (/remark-presenter-mode/.test(document.body.className)) return;

  // http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/getusermedia/intro/
  navigator.getUserMedia_ = navigator.getUserMedia || navigator.webkitGetUserMedia ||
    navigator.mozGetUserMedia || navigator.msGetUserMedia;
  if (!navigator.getUserMedia_) return;

  navigator.getUserMedia_({video: true, audio: false}, function(stream) {
    var video = document.getElementById('webcam');
    video.src = window.URL.createObjectURL(stream);
  }, function(e) {});
</script>
```

(2) You can include this HTML fragment in **xaringan** slides through the `includes` option (`after_body` sub-option). Or simply copy and paste into your Rmd source document (I didn't test the latter way).